# text justification function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm constructing a JavaScript function that takes a single-lined string of text and a length variable that is the expected justification width (longest word will never exceed this width). Here are more requirements:

- use spaces to fill in gaps between words
- each line needs to contain as many words as can fit within the length given.
- use `\n` (newline) to separate lines (not included in line length count)
- gap between words can't differ by more than one space
- lines need to end with word and not space
- space gaps go from larger to smaller across a line.
- last line does not get justification (single spacing ONLY) and cannot have `\n`
- strings with one word only need no space padding.

With no further ado, here's my code:

```
var justify = function(str, len) {

    var re = RegExp("(?:\\s|^)(.{1," + len + "})(?=\\s|$)", "g");
    var res = [];
    var finalResult = [];

    while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
      res.push(m[1]);  
    }

    var lastLine = res.pop();
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      var lineLength = res[i].length;
      if (lineLength !== len) {
        var toAdd = len - lineLength;
        var indexOf = res[i].indexOf(' ', 0);
        var str2 = res[i];
          if ( indexOf === -1 ) {
            str2;
          }
          while ( indexOf > -1 ) {
            str2 = str2.substring(0, indexOf + 1) + " " + str2.substring(indexOf + 1);
            if ( str2.length < len ) {
              indexOf = str2.indexOf(' ', (indexOf + 1));
            }
            else {
              break;
            }
          }

          finalResult.push(str2);
        }
    }

    finalResult.push(lastLine);

    return finalResult.join('\n');

}
```

I'm using a RegExp to carve out strings of or as nearly under the proscribed line length (`len`) and return each line as an element in a new array.  Last line is removed from array via `pop` and saved to a variable for future use on the finished array.  I then utilize a for loop to iterate over the line array and find out what needs to be added to the line length to get it to the `len` length.  I then split out each individual line according to the existing spaces (via .substring method) and add spaces to those spaces to pad out lines as needed.

Unfortunately, my code is not passing tests as I receive error messages indicating that the total number of lines is less than what's expected.  (i.e. `Line count is not equal 44 - Expected: 44, instead got: 40`).

I've noticed that my results also violate one of the code requirements (gaps between words must not differ by more than one space).  For example, one of my line justifies as follows (spaces are represented by colons `:`

`nisi::::volutpat:ac.`

How can I distribute the spacing more appropriately?  I believe I need to iterate over all the spaces, as my attempted iteration isn't actually working as intended.  I'm assuming once that's  resolved, the error with the line count discrepancy will also clear up.  Thank you for any tips or help.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but if you are doing this with the purpose of being able to justify your text, then take a look at the [`text-align: justify;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-align&preval=justify) and [`text-justify`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp) css properties.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
var justify = function(str, len) {

  var re = RegExp("(?:\\s|^)(.{1," + len + "})(?=\\s|$)", "g");
  var res = [];
  var finalResult = [];

  while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < res.length - 1; i++){    
    if(res[i].indexOf(' ') != -1){  
      while(res[i].length < len){      
        for(var j=0; j < res[i].length-1; j++){
          if(res[i][j] == ' '){
            res[i] = res[i].substring(0, j) + " " + res[i].substring(j);
            if(res[i].length == len) break;
            while(res[i][j] == ' ') j++;
          }
        }
      }      
    }    
    finalResult.push(res[i]);    
  }

  finalResult.push(res[res.length - 1]);

  return finalResult.join('\n');

}
```